# Sitecore XM Cloud Error: User is locked out

Tags: authentication, xm-cloud

I am using XMCloud on my local docker instance, but it locked my user after entering my cloud logins multiple times (by mistake). now when I am running my local URL to log into Sitecore it shows an error that the User is locked out. I can log into the cloud portal in all environments, but this is only on local. So far I tried multiple options including up and down the instance. Do we have any option to resolve the locked-out user or any alternative way to log in using an admin account?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a sql management studio or something similar, please follow this steps.
First find your docker network by:

```
docker network ls
```

then find out the IP of the Sql server using the docker inspect, for example:

```
docker inspect [Your Network Name or ID]

docker inspect xmcloud_default
```

which will show you the internal IP of the SQL:

```
   "93a5e82efb3a1ec6a14d91033564975d9b16c3eb82d8455e7141d35416f0233d": {
            "Name": "xmcloud-cm-1",
            "EndpointID": "49131e48c6ed7759b1e7a871b0979130c1cbb4bb504a2a26105d6679eaf606cb",
            "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:a7:c5:07",
            "IPv4Address": "172.29.158.178/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ee4b0eb869c7d5897372e6096ba22f0ac8bbb3805211932b5ead52ca9f4bf78d": {
            "Name": "xmcloud-mssql-1",
            "EndpointID": "8394fe5b5ecd2d56d3685202fd31c745c2df9e3bdd7ae801bec32aca940413df",
            "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:a7:c4:29",
            "IPv4Address": "172.29.154.34/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
```

Open the SQL management studio and connect to SQL using the ip (172.29.154.34). The username is `sa` and password is in your `.env` file variable `SQL_SA_PASSWORD`.

Find your user in `aspnet_Membership` table from `Sitecore.Core` database and set the `IsLockedout` to false.